# Easiest way to do VHDL floating point division?

Tags: vhdl, division, fpga

I'm looking for easiest way to divide two floating point numbers using VHDL. I need the code to be synthesizable (I'll be implementing it on Spartan 3 FPGA).

First operand will always be a fixed number (e.g. 600), and second one will be integer, let's say between 0 and 99999. Fixed number is dividend, and the integer one is divisor. So I'll have to calculate something like this: 600/124.
Or any other number instead of 124, of course that is in range between 0 and 99999. Second number (the one that is changing) will always be integer !! (there won't be something like 123.45).

After division, I need to convert the result into integer (round it up or just ignore numbers after decimal point, which ever is faster).

Any ideas ? Thanks !

Comment: Have you looked for examples from source code on opencores.org?

Comment: Which value is the divisor? This makes a big difference.

Comment: Also, there's big difference between 0 to 99999 and 0.000000 to 99999.000000. Can you clarify exactly the precision and range of all your values?

Comment: @DavidPointer: I've looked there, but there are only big FPU cores that support all mathematical operations. I want something smaller.

Comment: @Adam12: Fixed value is dividend, and the integer one is divisor. Divisor will always be integer between 0 and 99999. Divisor will never be a number like 1232.3344523 or any other floating point number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, with the easiest being a ROM. You don't need floating point anywhere since doing an integer divide and compensating for a non-zero remainder can give you the same results. I'd suggest calculating the first 600 results in MATLAB or a spreadsheet so you can see that handling values up to 99999 isn't necessary.

Also, some common nomenclature for range and precision is *QI.F* where I is the number of integer bits and F is the number of fractional bits. Thus 0..99999 would be Q17.0 and your output would be Q10.0.

Comment: Thanks ! I've decided to use integer division (repeated subtraction) and I've successfully implemented it.

Answer (score 3):

There's an FP divide function in [this VHDL file](http://www.eda.org/fphdl/float_pkg_c.vhdl) from this [site](http://www.eda.org/fphdl/old_index.html).